# AngularJS layout row not containing div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Body is currently set to layout="column" I have a header row and a content row inside it. The header row works just fine, but the content row is getting set to no height, or I set it to flex but either way it is overlapping the header row and I want to be able to set the inner divs to be 100% of the remaining height.

```
<body layout="column" ng-style="bodyStyle" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

<div class="header" layout="row">
  <div class="menuButton">
    <a href="#"><ng-md-icon icon="menu"></ng-md-icon></a>
    <md-tooltip>Menu</md-tooltip>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content" layout="row" style="background-color: black">
  <p>Random text asdf
  <div class="sidenav" layout="column">
    <div>
      <ng-md-icon icon="people"></ng-md-icon>
      <md-tooltip>Contacts</md-tooltip>
    </div>
    <div class="active">
      <a href="#"><ng-md-icon icon="message"></ng-md-icon></a>
      <md-tooltip>Conversations</md-tooltip>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><ng-md-icon icon="phone"></ng-md-icon></a>
      <md-tooltip>Phone Calls</md-tooltip>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#"><ng-md-icon icon="more_horiz"></ng-md-icon></a>
      <md-tooltip>More</md-tooltip>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="likeThis!">I want to be 100% of the remaining height</div>
</div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use `height:calc`

e.g.

```
.full-height {
height: calc(100%)
}
```

you can also use it like

```
.full-height {
    height: calc(100% - 20px)
    }
```

assuming 20px is height of your remaining stuff which is at the top.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's essentially what flex does. I tried both but but the inner divs still extend beyond that